# Moving jquery datePicker outside of iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, datepicker

I have an `iframe` inside my page... And this `iframe` is basically a simple form with date input field to which I binded jquery `datePicker`.

My problem is that `iframe` is pretty small in dimensions, so when I give my input field focus and `datepicker` rolls out, it's only partly shown and the rest is hidden inside of `iframe`.

My idea is move `datepicker` outside of this `iframe` to parent window (which I suceeded) and then move it to my input field location by myself. Therefore I will have `datepicker` in front of `iframe`.

**I moved the `datepicker` with this:**
(this code is inside the `iframe`)

```
$("#txtDate").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst)
    {
        inst.dpDiv[0].style.zIndex = '9999';
        window.parent.$('body').append(inst.dpDiv);
    }
});
```

And that's all fine, but the `datepicker` is now totally unresponsive. It does not respond to my clicking. Do you have any idea on how can I overcome this? I tried everything that poped up to my mind, but still haven't figured this out.

Comment: why not just lose the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Access the parent body element by below, solves the issue.It works in IE and does not work in Firefox

```
$('body', parent.document).append(inst.dpDiv);
```